# How to inject class in constructor of another class?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, dependencies

I have three projects com.comman, com.business in one solution and com.xyz in another solution.

In com.comman i have one class lets say logger, it takes one parameter in constructor. So in com.business i am referring commans DLL and creating logger obj as 
var obj=new logger("MIS");

Like this i want to create logger object in com.xyz but without referencing com.comman dll. Is it possible to achieve this?

NOTE: From com.business project i am calling one of the class called "ABC"of com.xyz which again calls another class "PQR" in com.xyz. I want to create logger object in PQR class.

Please guide me!!

Comment: are you talking about different solutions or projects? I don't think you can do that without referencing one project to another. You probbably can load DLL dynamically and use reflection if you absolutely don't want to use reference..

Comment: Yes, two different solutions, com.comman, com.business are in one solution and com.xyz is in another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that assembly `com.xyz` is not allowed to reference assembly `com.comman`, since `com.xyz` is in a different solution and that solution is already refering at `com.xyz`.

This means that the `PQR` class can't depend on `com.comman.Logger`. Still you want to be able to inject that logger in `PQR`.

The way to solve this is to define an abstraction/interface in `com.xyz` and let `PQR` depend on that interface. For instance:

```
// Logger abstraction specifically tailored at the needs of com.xyz
public class ILogger {
    void Log(string message);
}

public class PQR {
    private readonly ILogger logger;
    public PQR(ILogger logger) {
        if (logger == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("logger");
        this.logger = logger;
    }
    // PQR methods
}
```

The existence of this new `com.xyz.ILogger` abstraction allows you to create an adapter that maps from `com.xyz.ILogger` to `com.comman.logger`. This adapter should be located in the solution of `com.business`. The most preferable place for this is the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/). The Composition Root will likely be an assembly that refers your `com.business`, but if `com.business` is your start-up project, that would be the place to create the adapter.

This adapter might look as follows:

```
public class ComXyzLoggerAdapter : com.xyz.ILogger {
    private com.comman.logger logger;
    ComXyzLoggerAdapter(com.comman.logger logger)
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public void Log(string message) {
        // Here we map from com.xyz.ILogger to comman.Logger 
        this.logger.LogError(message);
    }
}
```

In the location where you create the `PQR` class (in the `com.business` solution) you will now need to do this:

```
var abc =
    new ABC(
        new QPR(
            new ComXyzLoggerAdapter(
                new com.comman.logger("MIS"))));
```

What we did here was basically applying the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle).

Comment: This is what i was looking for..Thanks!!